# Leaf Disease Detection and Recognition using OpenCV

Tags: android, c++, opencv

can you help me with this.

I was tasked to create an application using the OpenCV and c++ that would take in an image input of a plant leaf. This application would detect possible symptoms of disease like black/grey/brown spots from the leaf, or blights, lesions and etc. Each characteristic of disease such as color of the spots represents different diseases. After detecting the possible symptoms, the application will match it to the collection of template images from the application's database and will output a possible best match.

What methods do I have to use on this? I've researched Histogram Matching and Keypoint and Descriptor Matching but I'm not sure which one will work best.

I have found sample code using SURF and FLANN, but I don't know if this would be enough:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp"

using namespace cv;

void readme();

/**
* @function main
* @brief Main function
*/
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
if( argc != 3 )
{  readme(); return -1; }

Mat img_1 = imread( argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );
Mat img_2 = imread( argv[2], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );

if( !img_1.data || !img_2.data )
{ std::cout<< " --(!) Error reading images " << std::endl; return -1; }

//-- Step 1: Detect the keypoints using SURF Detector
int minHessian = 400;

SurfFeatureDetector detector( minHessian );

std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_1, keypoints_2;

detector.detect( img_1, keypoints_1 );
detector.detect( img_2, keypoints_2 );

//-- Step 2: Calculate descriptors (feature vectors)
SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor;

Mat descriptors_1, descriptors_2;

extractor.compute( img_1, keypoints_1, descriptors_1 );
extractor.compute( img_2, keypoints_2, descriptors_2 );

//-- Step 3: Matching descriptor vectors using FLANN matcher
 FlannBasedMatcher matcher;
 std::vector< DMatch > matches;
 matcher.match( descriptors_1, descriptors_2, matches );

 double max_dist = 0; double min_dist = 100;

 //-- Quick calculation of max and min distances between keypoints
for( int i = 0; i < descriptors_1.rows; i++ )
{ double dist = matches[i].distance;
if( dist < min_dist ) min_dist = dist;
if( dist > max_dist ) max_dist = dist;
 }

printf("-- Max dist : %f \n", max_dist );
printf("-- Min dist : %f \n", min_dist );

//-- Draw only "good" matches (i.e. whose distance is less than 2*min_dist,
//-- or a small arbitary value ( 0.02 ) in the event that min_dist is very
//-- small)
//-- PS.- radiusMatch can also be used here.
std::vector< DMatch > good_matches;

for( int i = 0; i < descriptors_1.rows; i++ )
{ if( matches[i].distance <= max(2*min_dist, 0.02) )
{ good_matches.push_back( matches[i]); }
}

//-- Draw only "good" matches
Mat img_matches;
drawMatches( img_1, keypoints_1, img_2, keypoints_2,
           good_matches, img_matches, Scalar::all(-1), Scalar::all(-1),
           vector<char>(), DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS );

//-- Show detected matches
imshow( "Good Matches", img_matches );

for( int i = 0; i < (int)good_matches.size(); i++ )
{ printf( "-- Good Match [%d] Keypoint 1: %d  -- Keypoint 2: %d  \n", i,           good_matches[i].queryIdx, good_matches[i].trainIdx ); }

 waitKey(0);

return 0;
}

  /**
  * @function readme
 */
    void readme()
 { std::cout << " Usage: ./SURF_FlannMatcher <img1> <img2>" << std::endl; }
```

Here are my questions:

1. What method do I have to use? Histogram Matching, Keypoint/Descriptor Matching or?
2. If I use Keypoint/Descriptor matching, what algorithm is best alternative to SURF and FLANN since I will be implementing it ALSO on an android platform? Do I still have to perform thresholding or segmentation? Will it not remove important details such as the color, shape or etc.? Please guys, suggests some steps to do this.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think your question is far too complex - there are far too many possible ways to implement this, and most of them very much non-trivial (there are many possible symptoms that you need to address with specific algorithms). I don't think that you'll find a pre-made algorithm that would match all your needs, especially with the task described in very vague terms.

Answer (score 1):

I think this way should give you good results:

Training process.

1. Extract LBP descriptors for exery pixel of image (can be computed
   for color images too).
2. Compute histograms of LBP descriptors for each training sample.
3. Train classifier using histograms as inputs and labels as outputs.

Prediction process:

1. Extract LBP descriptors for exery pixel of new image.
2. Compute histogram of LBP descriptors for this image.
3. Feed historgam to classifier -> get results.

I've successfully used feed forward neural network as classifier, for solving similar problem.

You may find this book useful: ISBN 978-0-85729-747-1 "Computer Vision Using Local Binary Patterns"

Try this (computes LBP descriptors, there is also function for computation of histogram):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>
#include "opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp"
#include <limits>
using namespace cv;

class myLBP
{
public:
    uchar lut[256];
    uchar null;
    int radius;
    int maxTransitions;
    bool rotationInvariant;

    myLBP(int _radius=1,int _maxTransitions=8,bool _rotationInvariant=false)
    {
        radius=_radius;
        maxTransitions=_maxTransitions;
        rotationInvariant=_rotationInvariant;

        bool set[256];
        uchar uid = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<256; i++)
        {
            if (numTransitions(i) <= maxTransitions)
            {
                int id;
                if (rotationInvariant)
                {
                    int rie = rotationInvariantEquivalent(i);
                    if (i == rie)
                    {
                        id = uid++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        id = lut[rie];
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    id = uid++;
                }
                lut[i] = id;
                set[i] = true;
            }
            else
            {
                set[i] = false;
            }
        }
        null = uid;
        for (int i=0; i<256; i++)
            if (!set[i])
            {
                lut[i] = null;    // Set to null id
            }
    }


    /* Returns the number of 0->1 or 1->0 transitions in i */
    static int numTransitions(int i)
    {
        int transitions = 0;
        int curParity = i%2;
        for (int j=1; j<=8; j++)
        {
            int parity = (i>>(j%8)) % 2;
            if (parity != curParity)
            {
                transitions++;
            }
            curParity = parity;
        }
        return transitions;
    }

    static int rotationInvariantEquivalent(int i)
    {
        int min = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
        for (int j=0; j<8; j++)
        {
            bool parity = i % 2;
            i = i >> 1;
            if (parity)
            {
                i+=128;
            }
            min = std::min(min, i);
        }
        return min;
    }

    void process(const Mat &src, Mat &dst) const
    {
        Mat m;
        src.convertTo(m, CV_32F);
        assert(m.isContinuous() && (m.channels() == 1));
        Mat n(m.rows, m.cols, CV_8UC1);
        n = null; // Initialize to NULL LBP pattern
        const float *p = (const float*)m.ptr();
        for (int r=radius; r<m.rows-radius; r++)
        {
            for (int c=radius; c<m.cols-radius; c++)
            {
                const float cval  =     (p[(r+0*radius)*m.cols+c+0*radius]);
                n.at<uchar>(r, c) = lut[(p[(r-1*radius)*m.cols+c-1*radius] >= cval ? 128 : 0) |
                    (p[(r-1*radius)*m.cols+c+0*radius] >= cval ? 64  : 0) |
                    (p[(r-1*radius)*m.cols+c+1*radius] >= cval ? 32  : 0) |
                    (p[(r+0*radius)*m.cols+c+1*radius] >= cval ? 16  : 0) |
                    (p[(r+1*radius)*m.cols+c+1*radius] >= cval ? 8   : 0) |
                    (p[(r+1*radius)*m.cols+c+0*radius] >= cval ? 4   : 0) |
                    (p[(r+1*radius)*m.cols+c-1*radius] >= cval ? 2   : 0) |
                    (p[(r+0*radius)*m.cols+c-1*radius] >= cval ? 1   : 0)];
            }
        }
        dst=n.clone();
    }

    /* Returns the number of 1 bits in i */
    static int bitCount(int i)
    {
        int count = 0;
        for (int j=0; j<8; j++)
        {
            count += (i>>j)%2;
        }
        return count;
    } 

    void draw(const Mat &src, Mat &dst) const
    {
        static Mat hueLUT, saturationLUT, valueLUT;
        if (!hueLUT.data)
        {
            const int NUM_COLORS = 10;
            hueLUT.create(1, 256, CV_8UC1);
            hueLUT.setTo(0);
            uchar uid = 0;
            for (int i=0; i<256; i++)
            {
                const int transitions = numTransitions(i);
                int u2;
                if   (transitions <= 2)
                {
                    u2 = uid++;
                }
                else
                {
                    u2 = 58;
                }
                // Assign hue based on bit count
                int color = bitCount(i);
                if (transitions > 2)
                {
                    color = NUM_COLORS-1;
                }
                hueLUT.at<uchar>(0, u2) = 255.0*(float)color/(float)NUM_COLORS;
            }
            saturationLUT.create(1, 256, CV_8UC1);
            saturationLUT.setTo(255);
            valueLUT.create(1, 256, CV_8UC1);
            valueLUT.setTo(255.0*(3.0/4.0));
        }
        if (src.type() != CV_8UC1)
        {
            std::cout << "Expected 8UC1 source type.";

        }
        Mat hue, saturation, value;
        LUT(src, hueLUT, hue);
        LUT(src, saturationLUT, saturation);
        LUT(src, valueLUT, value);
        std::vector<Mat> mv;
        mv.push_back(hue);
        mv.push_back(saturation);
        mv.push_back(value);
        Mat coloredU2;
        merge(mv, coloredU2);
        cvtColor(coloredU2, dst, cv::COLOR_HSV2BGR);
    } 
};


void Hist(const Mat &src, Mat &dst,float max=256, float min=0,int dims=-1)
{
    std::vector<Mat> mv;
    split(src, mv);
    Mat m(mv.size(), dims, CV_32FC1);
    for (size_t i=0; i<mv.size(); i++)
    {
        int channels[] = {0};
        int histSize[] = {dims};
        float range[] = {min, max};
        const float* ranges[] = {range};
        Mat hist, chan = mv[i];
        // calcHist requires F or U, might as well convert just in case
        if (mv[i].depth() != CV_8U && mv[i].depth() != CV_32F)
        {
            mv[i].convertTo(chan, CV_32F);
        }
        calcHist(&chan, 1, channels, Mat(), hist, 1, histSize, ranges);
        memcpy(m.ptr(i), hist.ptr(), dims * sizeof(float));
    }
    dst=m.clone();
}



int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cv::initModule_nonfree();
    cv::namedWindow("result");
    cv::Mat bgr_img = cv::imread("D:\\ImagesForTest\\lena.jpg");
    if (bgr_img.empty()) 
    {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    cv::Mat gray_img;
    cv::cvtColor(bgr_img, gray_img, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    cv::normalize(gray_img, gray_img, 0, 255, cv::NORM_MINMAX);

    myLBP lbp(1,2);
    Mat lbp_img;

    lbp.process(gray_img,lbp_img);
    lbp.draw(lbp_img,bgr_img);

    //for(int i=0;i<lbp_img.rows;++i)

    imshow("result",bgr_img);
    cv::waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply sir. . i'm sorry, but i'm kinda new to this. when you say LBP descriptors, is it the same with feature descriptors?

Comment: Yes, it is a kind of feature descriptors. I've updated my answer, try it.

Comment: thanks in advance sir. . i'll have to study it first and try it. it will be a big help i'm sure.

Comment: Andrey, do you have example of implementing neural network as a classifier?

Comment: You  can find one in stndard openCV's examples, take a look at PointsClassifier.cpp